# How Can I count clicks on a Href link and update mysql

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, count, click

I would like to update the status of a mysql table when a  Link is clicked.  The link is an external site link.

Im currently using a php file to generate the links menu and a .htm page to display it.

How can I update my database when a link is clicked.

Comment: Code would be a good start

Comment: so count clicks and store in db :)

Comment: you can try ajax and jquery

Comment: You can send links to php script which saves count to database and then redirects to url (given as query parameter) via HTTP header.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.,  Very much appreciated.  Yes, count clicks and store in DB.

Comment: @MillerKoijam, AJAX may not be possible as he is leaving the domain

Comment: @Pawan but the method to increment the count in the DB can be called using Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm describing here is to replace your links to an internal link that count visits then redirect visitor to the entended link.

- create a php file (ex. www.your-domain.com/my_file.php)
- replace your links this way:
- from:
  **www.another-domain.com**
  to:
  **www.your-domain.com/my_file.php?url=www.another-domain.com**
- code your php file so it save that www.another-domain.com is being visited and redirect user to that domain

for redirection use:

> header('Location: www.another-domain.com')